# Integrate the 2 Jenkins environments

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have running the Jenkins Pipeline job in Jenkins A instance. In that Jenkins Pipeline job I just wanted to talk/call the downstream job in Jenkins B instance .
Is there any way is there to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to configure your B instance's job to accept remote builds using [Remote Access API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API).

In instance B job configuration, enable "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)" checkbox and fill in a some token you decide.

Then from instance A job call `https://<instance-B-url>/<url-path-to-job>/build?token=<your-token>`, or if your the job has parameters `/buildWithParameters?token=<your-token>`. You can use [HTTP Request plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/), or simply `curl` it from the shell in Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Can we call the Instance B job in Instance A Jenkins File.